# Harmonic conjugate and resulting analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions, cauchy-riemann-equations

I can't quite figure out the last part of this problem...

Find a harmonic conjugate of the harmonic function $u(x,y)= x^3-3xy^2$. Write the resulting analytic function in terms of the complex variable z.

One harmonic conjugate of u is $v(x,y) = 6x^2y-y^3$ (probably wrong, but here's the calculation):

$v(x,y) = \int_{(x_0,y_0)}^{(x,y)} -u_t(s,t)ds + u_s(s,t)dt = \int_{(x_0,y_0)}^{(x,y)} 6st ds + (3s^2-3t^2)dt$

Choosing $(x_0,y_0) = (0,0)$ (since we're finding a harmonic conjugate):

$v(x,y) = 3x^2y+3x^2y-y^3 = 6x^2y-y^3$

So, the resulting analytic function is $f(z) = x^3 - 3x^2y + i(6x^2y-y^3)$ ($z = x+iy$)

How do you write this in terms of $z$? If it was $f(z) = x^3 - 3x^2y + i(3x^2y-y^3)$, it would be just $f(z) = z^3$, but with the $6$ in there, I don't know where to go.

Comment: The most likely explanation is that $v(x,y) = 6x^2y-y^3$ is *not* a harmonic conjugate of $u$, and that it should be $v(x,y) = 3x^2y-y^3$.

Comment: I mean I agree, but I have no idea where my error is... see my comments to the answer below, because I can't find the error when I'm using the contour integral.

Comment: Without seeing your calculations we cannot find to help the error ...

Comment: Calculations are above now, as well as below in the comments...

Comment: Then the error is probably in your calculation of $\int_{(x_0,y_0)}^{(x,y)} 6st \, ds$ ...

Comment: I'm not finding it, could you explain further? $u(s,t) = s^3 - 3st^2$, $u_t(s,t) = -6st$

Comment: I agree that's probably where the error is, but I've been looking for it for three days and could use some help :''D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> One harmonic conjugate of u is $v(x,y) = 6x^2y-y^3$ (probably wrong, ...

Indeed, that calculation is wrong. With the choice of $(x_0, y_0) = (0, 0)$ as initial point we have
$$
v(x, y) = \int_{(0, 0)}^{(x,y)} 6st \, ds + (3s^2-3t^2) \, dt \\
= \int_{(0, 0)}^{(x,0)} 6st \, ds + \int_{(x, 0)}^{(x,y)} 6st \, ds
+ \int_{(0, 0)}^{(x,0)} (3s^2-3t^2) \, dt + \int_{(x, 0)}^{(x,y)} (3s^2-3t^2) \, dt \, .
$$
The first integral is zero because $t=0$ on the path. The second and third integrals are zero because $ds=0$ respectively $dt=0$. It remains
$$
v(x, y) = \int_{(x, 0)}^{(x,y)} (3s^2-3t^2) \, dt = \int_0^y (3x^2 -3t^2) \, dt
= 3x^2 y- 3 \frac{y^3}{3} = 3x^2 y - y^3 \, .
$$
That is consistent with your observation that
$$
 z^3 = (x+iy)^3 =  x^3 - 3x^2y + i(3x^2y-y^3) \, .
$$
is an analytic function with the given real part $u$. The general solution is obtained by adding an arbitrary imaginary constant.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, $v(x,y)=3x^2y-y^3+k$, for some constant $k\in\mathbb R$. Therefore,\begin{align}f(x+yi)&=x^3-3xy^2+3x^2yi-y^3i+ki\\&=(x+yi)^3+ki.\end{align}So, $f(z)=z^3+ki$.

Comment: How do you get that conjugate? We're instructed to use $v(x,y) = \int_{(x_0,y_0)}^{(x,y)} -u_t(s,t)ds + u_s(s,t) dt$, so $v(x,y) = \int_{(x_0,y_0)}^{(x,y)} 6st ds + (3s^2-3t^2) dt = 6x^2y-y^3 + c$

Comment: I looked after a function $v$ such that $\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=-3y^2$. So, I took $v(x,y)=-y^3+k(x)$. In order to determine the function $k$, I chose it so that$$k'(x)=\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=-\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=6xy.$$

Comment: Weird, I get the same answer as you using that method, but using the method I'm required to use, I don't.